# how to protect my form by checking that 2 values are not the same?

Tags: webforms

I have a contact form created with webform module.
I have already add recaptcha on my form, but I received regularly some bad contacts.
To protect my form I want to check that field lastname and firstname have not the same value before the user click on submit button.

how can I do that.

thanks.

Comment: Does this have to do with spam or have to do with users not reading?

Comment: it's to protect from spam.